# JMeter Test Action Target ignored

Tags: jmeter

About Test Action Target behavior, According to [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) user manual Target is mandatory and `ignored for Pause`:

> `Target` Current Thread / All Threads (ignored for Pause) 
>   Required: Yes

But in fact also when choosing Action: `Go to next loop iteration` the Target is disabled and not required.

Should it be marked as not required (N) and ignored also for Action `Go to next loop iteration`? and maybe be disabled also when choosing Action Pause  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a bug reported here:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61707

And now fixed, it will be available in next JMeter version following 3.3.